# Mandrill send template doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mandrill

want to use template to send a mail. 
my template is:

> Hi {{username}} we {{msg}}

The problem is that I can't use the username and msg parameters. It just sends the raw template.

I use global_merge_vars and merge_vars on other instance:

```
global_merge_vars: [{
    name: 'username',
    content: '123123'
}, {
    name: 'lala',
    content: '444444'
}]
```

. What can be the problem?
I use Nodejs client.

Answer (score 0):

Defining "merge_language" parameter as "mailchimp" instead of "handlebars" caused my problem.